# @wire getting called automatically when switching between tabs in Lightning Console

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I see a very weird behaviour, in which the `@wire` is being called every time, I switch between tabs after 30 seconds. (Lighting console tab)

Here is the code:

```
  @api recordId;

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: "$recordId", 
    fields: [
        TAG_NAME, OWNERSHIP_TYPE, PRIMARY_OWNER
    ]})
async wiredAccount({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('data => ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('error => ' + error);
    }
}
```

Metadata has :

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>
```

Its a simple code using `getRecord`.

More interesting part is, I am not able to replicate the same in other environments. Only is replicable in client's org.

Anyone faced this issue before?

As a solution I can probably add a boolean value to not process anything inside `wiredAccount` if it is being called second time. But wanted to check if others have faced any similar issue?

Comment: Could you add information regarding `recordId`? Is this @api on a lightning__RecordPage or how is this set?

Comment: Yes, updated the information

Comment: The `recordId` is reactive, but it should not affect wire lifecycle, as it does not gets changed. Also the strange part if that it happens only after 30 seconds.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as written. Wire methods may fire any time they detect a record has changed. For example, if [notifyRecordUpdateAvailable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-notify-record-update.html) is called, wires that are bound to `$recordId` that match the record Id provided in the function call will update as a result. There may be another component elsewhere in that org that's causing the refresh.

Comment: @sfdcfox this is the only component in the page, which reloads. And I added a console log to verify that only the wired method of this component gets called. I also added a console.log on `connectedCallback` and that does not get called.